# How can I log in via ssh into a chroot

Tags: ssh, chroot

I have a Synology NAS and was frustrated with the available packages. So I installed a Debian chroot (after a lot of googling, as I am just a normal user). This is great. Now I would like to work remotely with VS Code on some py files which reside inside the chroot. Until now I always had to connect via ssh to the NAS and then enter the chroot. Is there a way that I can connect via ssh directly to the chroot and therefore also connect with VS Code to the chroot?

Best regards
MH

Answer (score 0):

A friend told me to configure sshd to use another port and then to connect directly. This seems to work. Now I get another error message regarding tty, but this is another topic.